# Error while installing any packages in 21.04

Tags: apt, 21.04

I am getting the following error while using `apt install` :

```
/usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot: 18: .: cannot open /lib/cryptsetup/functions: No such file
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/cryptroot failed with return 2.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-31-generic with 2.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error   exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As per suggestion by @Karel:

Received following errors while installing `cryptsetup`

```
 update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-31-generic
 Error: /sbin/zdb is not executable.
 Error: /sbin/zpool is not executable.
 Error: /sbin/zfs is not executable.
 Error: /sbin/mount.zfs is not executable.
 Error: /lib/udev/vdev_id is not executable.
 Error: /lib/udev/zvol_id is not executable.
 E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/zfs failed with return 2.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-31-generic    with 2.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script        subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the following error message:

> cannot open /lib/cryptsetup/functions: No such file

`/lib/cryptsetup/functions` is provided by cryptsetup in Ubuntu 20.04 and later.

1. Run `dpkg -l *5.11.0-31*|grep ii` to list installed packages which contain the string `5.11.0-31` in their names.
2. Purge the packages which contain the string `5.11.0-31` in their names from the previous step with `sudo dpkg -P package_name` but be careful to purge only the `linux-` kernel and support file package names.
3. Run `sudo update-grub` to rebuild the GRUB boot menu.
4. Run `sudo reboot` to reboot.
5. Install cryptsetup.

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install cryptsetup
   ```

Comment: got some errors while installing `cryptsetup`. Kindly see the edited question for errors.